# tuple to numpy, data accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, floating-accuracy

When I convert a tuple to numpy, there is a problem with data accuracy. My code is like this:

```
import numpy as np
a=(0.547693688614422, -0.7854270889025808, 0.6267478456110592)
print(a)
print(type(a))
tmp=np.array(a)
print(tmp)
```

The result is like this:

```
(0.547693688614422, -0.7854270889025808, 0.6267478456110592)
<class 'tuple'>
[ 0.54769369 -0.78542709  0.62674785]
```

Why?

Comment: did any of the answers below answer your question? If so please mark them as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set this:

```
In [1039]: np.set_printoptions(precision=20)

In [1041]: tmp=np.array(a)

In [1042]: tmp
Out[1042]: array([ 0.547693688614422 , -0.7854270889025808,  0.6267478456110592])

In [1043]: tmp.dtype
Out[1043]: dtype('float64')
```

Comment: @June-Solstice The dtype is `float` only. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only seeing a truncation in *display* only, but the **internal value still retains the original accuracy**.  Here's what I found:

```
>> a
(0.547693688614422, -0.7854270889025808, 0.6267478456110592)

>> b=np.array(a)

>> b
array([ 0.54769369, -0.78542709,  0.62674785]) #<-- printed display shows lower accuracy

>> b[0]
0.547693688614422 #<-- print of a single value shows same accuracy as original
```

So there's no reason to change any settings - math performed with these arrays will still be at full accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This seeming discrepancy should just be how the numbers are being displayed, not how they are being represented / stored.

You can check the `dtype` to verify it is still float64

```
tmp.dtype  # dtype('float64')
```

You can adjust `np.set_printoptions` to see them values displayed differently

```
print(tmp)  # [ 0.54769369 -0.78542709  0.62674785]
np.set_printoptions(precision=18)  # default precision is 8
print(tmp)  # [ 0.547693688614422  -0.7854270889025808  0.6267478456110592]
```